# Distinct minimum spanning tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, branch-cuts

For a connected, weighed, undirected graph G: G has a unique MST, if for every cut of G there is a unique minimum weight edge crossing the cut.

Is this statement true?

I think false because for the following graph in the given link there can be multiple MSTs.

[image]

Comment: I think the minimum weight edge in the question is not necessary a minimum weight edge in the whole $G$ but only a minimum weight edge among the edges crossed by the cut.  Then for the graph from the picture a cut consisting of the upper left vertex has two minimum weight edges.

Comment: Maybe we can prove the statement using a fact that the condition imposed on the graph  assures that [Jarník-Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) build a unique minimum spanning tree from any given starting vertex.